# How to deduce the XOR variant of the Full 1bit adder circuit design?

Tags: logic, xor

I'm trying to figure out how to find the short version of Sum in a full adder, from the truth table I got this DNF:

`(A && ~B && ~C) || (~A && B && ~C) || (~A && ~B && C) || (A && B && C)`

where `A = A`, `B = B`, and `C = CIn`

But according to wikipedia, this is equivalent to:

`A XOR B XOR C`

Is there a way I can somehow figure out the latter version or do I just need to "see it" in the truth table?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The terms in your [DNF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjunctive_normal_form) have one thing in common: An **odd** number of inputs is true.

The output line of a [full-adder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Full-adder#Full_adder) is `1` if and when an odd number (one or three) of its input lines are `1`. If zero inputs are `1` (= all are `0`), the output is `0`. If two inputs are `1`, carry-out is `1` but output stays `0`.

When you translate your truth table into a [Karnaugh map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karnaugh_map), you get the checker-board pattern typical for [XORs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_gate). In the end you are right: It does in fact help to "see it".

[image]

(Karnaugh map image copied from [here](http://www.exploreroots.com/dk5.html))